# Try to generate frame title followed by a underline

Tags: beamer, frame-title

I manage to set the frame title followed by a underline, it does not seem to be working, the line does not stretch to the edge:

```
\newcommand{\titlerule}[2][0ex]{\leaders\hbox{{\color{PrimaryColor}\rule[#1]{1pt}{#2}}}\hfill}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,left,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle\ \titlerule[0.5ex]{0.55pt}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please always add a small, but compilable test document and not just a code fragment. Creating a test document took about 10 times as long as actually testing potential solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `left` option of a `beamercolorbox` is basically an horizontal fill inserted on the the right side of the box. This means that the remaining space is equally distributed between the `\hfill` from your rule and the `\hfill` from the `left` option.

Without the option:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\titlerule}[2][0ex]{\leaders\hbox{{\color{red}\rule[#1]{1pt}{#2}}}\hfill}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle\ \titlerule[0.5ex]{0.55pt}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]